# Loading code in Android after gui

Tags: android, performance

Currently when I'm starting one of my Activities I want it to access several web pages and download things from there (including about 8000 lines of Json). All of that code is taking quite a while. Currently the code is all like this.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading_mods);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    // gets ad from google
    AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.ad);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

    // prepare for a progress bar dialog
    bar = (ProgressBar) (this.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1));
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    bar.setMinimumWidth((width / 5 * 2));
    bar.setMax(3);
    bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toMods);
    text.setText("Checking for updates...");

    UpdateChecker update = new UpdateChecker();
    update.execute(getBaseContext());

    try
    {
        if (update.get() == true)
        {
            bar.setMax(5);
            text.setText("Downloading update..");
            UpdateMods updater = new UpdateMods();
            updater.execute(getBaseContext());
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ExecutionException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem right now is that it takes a really long time to get the Gui to show up even though (as far as I know) it's done after text.setText("Checking for updates...")
However, the gui doesn't actually show up untill it is at or past the text.setText("Downloading update..") line.
When I was searching for some more info about how to do it I found this Image:
http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png

I pretty much know that I don't want it to run in onCreate, because it will take too long to get the gui. Nor in onStart or onResume are also not possible, because I don't want it to download the 8000+ line file every time I start the activity.

So where should I run this code? (UpdateChecker and UpdateMods being 2 ASyncTasks)

Comment: If you define your AsyncTask inside your Activity class, you are able then to update your gui, when onPostExecute is called by the AsyncTask

Comment: what's the point of an asynctask if you always immediatly call get() right after execute ?

Comment: I can't place the code from either of the ASyncs in the Activity code, because it uses URLs which can't be done in the main thread and have to be in an ASync.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
if (update.get() == true)
```

That is saying, in effect, "block the main application thread and freeze the UI until `doInBackground()` is complete".

Get rid of that line. Instead, make modifications to your UI based on the task's completion in `onPostExecute()` of the `AsyncTask`.